# Google Chrome - Open pop-ups in new tab?

Tags: google-chrome, popups

Is there a way to set Google Chrome so that it opens pop-ups in tabs instead of opening new windows?

Comment: This bug is exactly what the OP is asking for; go star it! [https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=10511](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=10511)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a 3 step workaround you can do this by

- You should know when the popup will be opened. Popups are blocked in chrome by default. But chrome will show a popup blocked notification in bottom right corner.
- click on notification to select always accept popup from this specific site
- Reload the main (parent) page. This will load the popup in small windows. Right click in titlebar of popup window and select "Show As Tab". Once popup is transformed in a window with tab, you can drag it back to main window.

Hope this helps.

Thanks.

Comment: This works, but it's a fiddle. I need to do this operation several times a day. It's shame it can't be more automated.

Answer (score 16):

There is the chrome extension [One Window](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/papnlnnbddhckngcblfljaelgceffobn).

It is not perfect, as the popup will first be opened and then "transformed" into a tab, which you will see as a flicker. Otherwise it seems to work fine.

Comment: Unfortunately, I may not always want just one window. There are times where I want to open a new window and have any popups generated from tabs in that window to join to that window.

Comment: The link is no longer valid and there seems to be no Chrome extension by that name now.

Comment: Still using the old version of this extension under developer mode as it's no longer available in Chrome Store. Still the best one out there.

Answer (score 4):

In Firefox, you can do this easily by [changing the config](https://superuser.com/q/128634/485660). But as for now, Google Chrome does not have anything like this, and it's annoying.

However, you can use a third-party extension to do this. I'm using ['Open link in same tab, pop-up as tab [Free]'](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/open-link-in-same-tab-pop/jmphljmgnagblkombahigniilhnbadca) extension offered by [sergiy.net](https://sergiy.net/theone/) and it works perfectly.

Extension's Privacy Policy: https://sergiy.net/theone/privacy_policy.html

[image: Screenshot]

You can check whether this is working or not by using the following site. (Use 'Try it' button)
https://js.do/code/google-chrome-open-pop-ups-in-new-tab

Comment: The link to popuptest.com is spam.

Comment: @Polshgiant, Thx; link is updated.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about a setting that will make pop-ups open in tabs but you can Right-Click the top bar of the window (with the page title), select "Show As Tab" and then drag it to your main window.

Comment: The accepted answer seems to be targeted at some specific web site that isn't even in the question any more.

Answer (score 0):

As of current chrome no there is not. When addons are more prevalent I can't see this as being hard to code in. I wouldn't be surprised if there wasn't one already if you run chrome with the `--enable-extensions` flag if you have the latest dev version of chrome and can find an addon|extensions that does this.

Comment: I think the latest beta builds have extensions enabled by default. I removed the --enable-extensions bit and they still work.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use those extensions, then the most simple solution is to Ctrl + Click the link you think it's a pop-up: it will be open as a new tab.

Comment: That requires predicting in advance what the pop-ups will be and also doesn't work for Javascript links.

Comment: In that case, it's necessary to use a browser which opens all links, including pop-ups in new tabs, such as Maxthon, until Chrome has that ability.

Answer (score 0):

[Popup Intercept - One Window](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/popup-intercept-one-windo/fpkgadnkojegbmhdflhhcjkhgjijiakm)

Is my next solution to One Window. The only downside for me is that you need to explicitly add each of the websites to be able make it work. I'm now using an unpacked version of this to make it work with all sites.