# Add the full firefox header to a popup

Tags: firefox, browser-addons, toolbar, popups

I have popup that I want to use some of my firefox tools on.

The popup only has a status bar on it right now.  How can I get all the normal firefox toolbars (like forward, back, home, address bar, etc.)?

Comment: How are you creating this popup?  Through code?  This might be more suitable for Stack Overflow...

Answer (score 2):

You can force all popups to open in tabs instead of new windows. New tabs can't get rid of toolbars etc. See [my answer](https://superuser.com/questions/128634/how-do-i-make-all-pop-ups-in-ff-open-in-a-new-tab-rather-then-a-new-window/128647#128647) to "How do I make ALL pop ups in FF open in a new tab rather then a new window?".

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is possible in a pop-up to show all toolbars. Best thing to do is right click the pop-up content, click "View Page Info".

In the window that pops up select and copy the "Address" and paste it in a normal tab. From there you should be able to do your thing.

Answer (score 1):

[Configuration Mania](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/4420) has options to force popups to show things like scrollbars, toolbars, menu bars, etc.  It's universal, but I much prefer having my popups have those things anyway.