# Forcing Browser to open all links in new tabs

Tags: browser, tabs

I am on a page and I need to open a link. Right now, I have to press `ctrl` and then click the link then it opens in a new tab. I don't want to do this.

What I want is that whenever I click any link it should always open in a new tab. Is this possible with Firefox or Chrome or  any other browser?

Comment: This question may be of particular benefit for users of the [_Vimium_](https://vimium.github.io) browser extension (or equivalent).

Answer (score 1):

There is no setting in Chrome for this that I know of, however...

You could **use a chrome extension**: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/open-new-blank-in-new-bac/bblhflcbilbefagmeoanbdiofmmnehda

Or just **middle click links** (by clicking with your scrollwheel) instead of <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>click</kbd> (works in Firefox too).

[This answer](https://superuser.com/a/128647/75775) might be helpful for Firefox.

Comment: What is middle click??

Comment: Oh do you mean pressing the scroll key?

Comment: @IcyFlame Some mice have a middle mouse button / scroll-wheel.

Answer (score 1):

You can add that functionality to Firefox with this add on: [*Open Link In New Tab*](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/open-link-in-new-tab/).

[image]

Personally I have got into the habit of right-clicking on links and choosing "Open Link in New Tab" from there.

Right click!

[image]

Comment: Big help for a Firefox + [_Vimium_](https://vimium.github.io) user like myself, thanks.